# JemmmyFX in Event mode

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jemmy, jemmyfx

I want to use JemmyFx for testing JavaFx applications. In Jemmyv2, we were able to start Jemmy in either event or robot-mode.  However, it seems that only Robot mode is available in Jemmy3.

I tried looking into the source code, especially that of JemmyAWTInput, and i could only find robot related class such as AWTRobotFactory.

Does anyone have an idea if  JemmyFX could be launched in event mode, i.e. non robot mode.

Answer (score 1):

Event dispatching is not implemented for JavaFX. There is no reliable way to do that.